# In Scrapy's ItemLoader, how to combine a custom parse method with TakeFirst()?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm to refactor a spider I've written to scrape APK download pages such as http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/adobe/photoshop-mix/photoshop-mix-1-0-333-release/adobe-photoshop-mix-1-0-333-beta-android-apk-download/. Here is the spider so far:

```
DEBUG = True

import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from apkmirror_scraper.items import ApkmirrorScraperItem, ApkmirrorItemLoader


class ApkmirrorSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'apkmirror-spider'
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [(r'.*-android-apk-download/$', 'parse')]

    if DEBUG:
        custom_settings = {'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20,
                           'CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT': 0,
                           'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 16,
                           'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 8}

    def parse(self, response):
        l = ApkmirrorItemLoader(item=ApkmirrorScraperItem(), response=response)

        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_xpath(field_name='title', xpath='//h1[@title]/text()')
        l.add_xpath(field_name='developer', xpath='//h3[@title]/a/text()')
        l.add_xpath(field_name='app', xpath='//*[contains(@data-channel-name, "App Updates")]/@data-channel-name')

        return l.load_item()
```

where I am trying to move the processing and parsing of the item field's into `items.py`:

```
import re

import scrapy
import scrapy.loader

from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, TakeFirst

class ApkmirrorScraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    developer = scrapy.Field()
    app = scrapy.Field()


def parse_app(data_channel_name):
    '''Parse the name of the app from the "data-channel-name" attribute of the button named "Follow [app_name] Updates".'''
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<app>.+) App Updates')
    return pattern.search(data_channel_name).groupdict().get("app")

class ApkmirrorItemLoader(scrapy.loader.ItemLoader):

    url_out = TakeFirst()

    title_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    title_out = TakeFirst()

    developer_in = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    developer_out = TakeFirst()

    app_out = MapCompose(parse_app)
```

Currently, if I crawl the spider it will scrape items like this:

```
2017-04-24 19:30:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/adobe/photoshop-mix/photoshop-mix-1-0-333-release/adobe-photoshop-mix-1-0-333-beta-android-apk-download/> (referer: http://www.apkmirror.com/apps_post-sitemap5.xml)
2017-04-24 19:30:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/adobe/photoshop-mix/photoshop-mix-1-0-333-release/adobe-photoshop-mix-1-0-333-beta-android-apk-download/>
{'app': [u'Adobe Photoshop Mix'],
 'developer': u'Adobe',
 'title': u'Adobe Photoshop Mix 1.0.333 beta (arm)',
 'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/adobe/photoshop-mix/photoshop-mix-1-0-333-release/adobe-photoshop-mix-1-0-333-beta-android-apk-download/'}
```

Note that the `'app'` field is still a list, which I would still like to apply Scrapy's `TakeFirst()` processor to. However, if I try to change the relevant line to

```
app_out = MapCompose(parse_app, TakeFirst())
```

I get items which look like this:

```
2017-04-24 19:44:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/powerpoint/powerpoint-16-0-6228-1008-release/powerpoint-16-0-6228-1008-android-apk-download/> (referer: http://www.apkmirror.com/apps_post-sitemap12.xml)
2017-04-24 19:44:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/powerpoint/powerpoint-16-0-6228-1008-release/powerpoint-16-0-6228-1008-android-apk-download/>
{'app': [u'M'],
 'developer': u'Microsoft Corporation',
 'title': u'Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0.6228.1008 (arm)',
 'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/powerpoint/powerpoint-16-0-6228-1008-release/powerpoint-16-0-6228-1008-android-apk-download/'}
```

where the `app` is `'M'` instead of `'Microsoft PowerPoint'`. In other words, it seems like `TakeFirst()` is taking the first letter of the string rather than the first item from the list. If I try switching around the order to `MapCompose(TakeFirst(), parse_app)`, then I get errors like

```
2017-04-24 19:49:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google/google-6-8-0-107974459-release/google-6-8-0-107974459-android-4-0-3-android-apk-download/> (referer: http://www.apkmirror.com/apps_post-sitemap13.xml)
2017-04-24 19:49:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google/google-6-8-0-107974459-release/google-6-8-0-107974459-android-4-0-3-android-apk-download/> (referer: http://www.apkmirror.com/apps_post-sitemap13.xml)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/kurt/dev/apkmirror_scraper/apkmirror_scraper/spiders/sitemap_spider.py", line 43, in parse
    return l.load_item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 115, in load_item
    value = self.get_output_value(field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 128, in get_output_value
    (field_name, self._values[field_name], type(e).__name__, str(e)))
ValueError: Error with output processor: field='app' value=[u'Google+ App Updates'] error='AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict''
```

In other words, the `parse_app` method fails.

How can I incorporate `TakeFirst()` into the `ItemLoader`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the desired result by using the custom parse method as an input processor and `TakeFirst()` as an output processor:

```
app_in = MapCompose(parse_app)
app_out = TakeFirst()
```

The scraped fields are now like

```
2017-04-24 19:55:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/excel/excel-16-0-6228-1008-release/excel-16-0-6228-1008-android-apk-download/> (referer: http://www.apkmirror.com/apps_post-sitemap12.xml)
2017-04-24 19:55:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/excel/excel-16-0-6228-1008-release/excel-16-0-6228-1008-android-apk-download/>
{'app': u'Microsoft Excel',
 'developer': u'Microsoft Corporation',
 'title': u'Microsoft Excel 16.0.6228.1008 (arm)',
 'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/microsoft-corporation/excel/excel-16-0-6228-1008-release/excel-16-0-6228-1008-android-apk-download/'}
```

with the full name of the app.